# Is there a way to restrict user access to their own work items in Azure DevOps Boards?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, workitem

Using Azure DevOps, I received a request from the business to restrict user access to their own (meaning, created by or assigned to them) work items in Azure DevOps Boards.
I created different areas for the corresponding teams, I am able to restrict view/edit of the areas, and with this team A can see work items in area A but not area B. This is fine, however not granular enough for my need.

Is there a way to restrict the user to see their own work items only and not the entire team's work items? I know this kind of defeat the purpose of collaborative work but business requirements are business requirements :(

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Give each user their own area path? That's about all you can do.

Comment: @DanielMann thanks for your suggestion. I thought about this solution, although it´s not  something feasible at scale.

Comment: I agree, it's not. I'm very curious to know why this is being asked of you. Like you said, what's the point in using a collaboration tool if people can't use it to collaborate?

Comment: Indeed. I have just created a single-user team for each user, with their dedicated area path. This way they are completely isolated from each other and cannot see other team's (individual´s) work items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed. I have just created a single-user team for each user, with their dedicated area path. This way they are completely isolated from each other and cannot see other team's (individual´s) work items.

Comment: I am trying the same thing, still, the user can see work items outside his dedicated area. 

What I did is set the default area for a team with one member only to a dedicated area, and assign the work items for this individual only to that specific area. Yet the subject still can see all work items.

Comment: To clarify, I am using the on-premise version

Comment: Hi @Majidkhalili, the trick here is to remove permissions of the other areas, otherwise the default permission set will allow the user to see the work items. You can do this either by removing "allow" permissions or adding "deny" permissions.

Comment: Thanks @AleNeoSP, yes you are right, I had to explicitly remove their other teams read permissions